# I need some intuition about the "trust_radius" in scipy's trust-ncg minimization method

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to minimize a fairly complex and non-linear problem, and since I have analytic Jacobians and Hessians at my disposal, I'd like to use Newton Conjugate Gradient minimization within scipy. However, I'm not getting very good results with the `Newton-CG` method of `scipy.optimize.minimize`, and started tinkering with the `trust-ncg` method instead. I **am** getting better results, so I want to use this minimization method. My problem is that I really don't have **any** sense for what the 'trust radius' is, so I'm just blindly setting values for the `initial_trust_radius` and `max_trust_radius` parameters.

The only reference I've seen for this method in the scipy documentation is [this paper](http://users.eecs.northwestern.edu/~morales/PSfiles/2157277.pdf), which gives some intuition on the `eta` parameter, but that's all I could glean. I'm really hoping someone can provide some intuition on what the size of the trust region means, in terms of the data that are actually being used and the minimization problem at hand.

Thanks!!

-b

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docstring of _minimize_trust_ncg](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/98649cd4121cf060694ec22c2960b2f69e6378b0/scipy/optimize/_trustregion_ncg.py#L19):

```
initial_trust_radius : float
    Initial trust-region radius.
max_trust_radius : float
    Maximum value of the trust-region radius. No steps that are longer
    than this value will be proposed.
eta : float
    Trust region related acceptance stringency for proposed steps.
gtol : float
    Gradient norm must be less than `gtol` before successful
    termination.
```

In another function, a bit deeper inside the algorithm and [a few lines later in the same file](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/98649cd4121cf060694ec22c2960b2f69e6378b0/scipy/optimize/_trustregion_ncg.py#L52):

```
    Parameters
    ----------
    trust_radius : float
        We are allowed to wander only this far away from the origin.
    Returns
    -------
    p : ndarray
        The proposed step.
    hits_boundary : bool
        True if the proposed step is on the boundary of the trust region.
    Notes
    -----
    This is algorithm (7.2) of Nocedal and Wright 2nd edition.
    Only the function that computes the Hessian-vector product is required.
    The Hessian itself is not required, and the Hessian does
    not need to be positive semidefinite.
```

So it seems that the trust radius is the size of the region that is investigated in each iteration of the algorithm. That's very useful if you know something about the smoothness of the function (or frequency domain of the data) that you are minimising over.

I'll get `Nocedal and Wright` from my university library soon and update the question if I gain some more insight.